# Asset thumbs missing in control panel after Assets Source update

Tags: assets, control-panel, image

I've updated several Assets Sources on my production site. I've exported / imported the database from production into local - the new Assets Sources are in place but the asset thumbs are now missing.

How can I get Craft to re-generate these please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My basePath was wrong in my config (due to a DropBox syncing issues). Once I corrected that and cleared caches, the asset thumbs reappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings > Clear Caches. Should regenerate them all from the new source.

Comment: Yes, tried this - and 'Update Asset Indexes' from Settings too. But neither worked.

Comment: Have you double checked your asset path?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before, and it was always either:

- Needed to update the URL in Settings > General
- Needed to change permissions on thumbs directory.
- Needed to delete thumbs directory.

Comment: I'm setting the siteUrl in the config - so that part is correct. But where is the thumbs directory?

Comment: craft/storage/runtime/assets